# Custom layout for a list activity Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listactivity

I know there is a lot of similiar questions, but I didn't find the answer that would help me, so this is my question. I have managed to do this:
[image: AS IS]

But what I want is this:
[image: TO BE]

So I want a fixed button at the bottom of the screen. And my layout is a custom layout for a ListActivity and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    >
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Delete" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" 
    />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you've pasted looks like a custom layout for the list rows, not the `ListActivity`.

From the Android documentation found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> Screen Layout
>
> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in thecenter of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)