# ListActivity error: “Unfortunately your app has stopped”

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my code in the Main Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String [] mainScreenList = {"Portal","Settings","Help","About"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> mainScreen = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, android.R.id.text1,mainScreenList);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(mainScreen);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String pen = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the pen: " + " " + pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //get selected items
       /* if(position==0)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DataEntryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else if(position==1)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DataEntryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else if(position==2)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DataEntryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else if(position==3)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DataEntryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }*/
    }
}
```

At the moment I am only trying to show the name of the list view item selected.

This is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bernine.practicalsessions.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        />
</ListView>
```

When running the app it says "Unfortunately the app has stopped."

Comment: Listview inside listview..????

Comment: refer this [List Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148920/custom-layout-for-a-list-activity-android?answertab=votes#tab-top), for setting custom layout for `ListActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once check out the `activity_main.xml` layout file. You have included `ListView` in another `ListView`. that is not valid.

include `ListView` in any container like `LinearLayout ,RelativeLayout , etc.` And for `ListView` you should use id as `@android:id/list`. 
once check out this sample layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I arranged it as you mentioned using Linear Layout and placed the id in the ListView Container. However, in the MainActivity.java in this line of code ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);  - 'cannot resolve symbol list'

Comment: use   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! Still new to Android :)